# Does a linker or loader need to understand every instruction in the target architecture?

Tags: linker

Does a linker or loader need to understand every instruction in the target architecture?
If a new model of the target adds new instructions, will the linker need to be existing instructions, will the linker need to be changed to support them? What if the model adds new addressing modes to existing instructions??

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe your programming problem? Are you trying to write a linker? Share some code and point out specifically where your problem is.

Comment: I'd have initially said no, but now I'd change it to: "Good question actually!"

Comment: @PaulStelian It depends what kind of linker you're writing. Presumably, the OP is having trouble writing a linker. OP should describe what that problem is, instead of asking theoretical questions, because once you've written a linker, the answer is obvious (because you had to solve it in order to write that linker).